# Can I make my home screen the center instead of the left?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5

I have the Nexus 5 from Google Play running stock Android 4.4.2. My home button takes me to the far **left** panel (the one next to Google Now). I added a panel to the left of it, but that changed my home button to taking me to *that* panel. Is there a way I can configure it to  go to the center panel? I'd really prefer not to have to install another launcher.

Comment: I've configured in some version of my Moto G. It is almost a stock Android. Its glass is now broken and I've just bought an Moto E, but can't a way to customize it. Both have Android 5.0.2, and in the Moto G the middle screen is the main one. I can't do the same in the new Moto E.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently, the default google launcher does not allow **any** customisation. In order to go to a particular screen, you need a custom launcher. There is no other way around it.

Comment: +1, it's totally un customisable really. I'm using Nova launcher and you can exactly emulate everyting from the GEL with the obvious exception of the Google Now integration. If you don't want that then you can set Icon size to 115%, get rid of the "Apps and Widets" headings on the App Drawer, set the notification bar to transparent, Icon Set to Kitkat and the font to Condensed and you will have exactly what you are used to (with the addition of many tweaks like gestures, transparancy settins, hide apps in drawer and so on).

Comment: I guess I'm going shopping for launchers. Thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I'm a bit mad for messing with settings etc on these things. Spent my bus journey this morning getting the GEL to match Nova launcher! I need to get out more. If I can help with anything at all let me know, otherwise enjoy the fiddling! Just to mention there are many other launchers like Apex, GoLauncher etc etc, but for me Nova is the lightest and best (but that's entirely subjective). It's one of very few apps I happily paid money for the pro version! Try a few and see what you like, it's really just your preferences. I've gone for very 'stock' like lately, slower animations etc.

Comment: Yeah, performance is key. I value my phone staying responsive above all else.

Comment: To match GEL in NOVA: Icon Size: 115% App Drawer Transparancy: About 33%ish. Icon Set: KitKat. App Drawer: Remove the headers for 'Apps' and 'Widgets', setting called "Small Tabs". Font: Condensed. Animation speed: Google. Status Bar: Transparent. Scroll Indicator: The round dots. Persistent Search Bar: Turned on as GEL has it. App Drawer is 6x4 icons. Colour Theme: White. Folders: Light background. Dock Height: Large.  That should cover it mostly. It's not 100% the same but it's very damn close!

Answer (score 1):

This works for my Samsung Galaxy Core LTE (SM-G386W), with the default Android 4.4.2:

1. Go to the home screens;
2. Press and hold on an empty spot to activate the settings;
3. The default home screen should have a house symbol on its top side,
   and it should be highlighted with white margins;
4. The default home screen can be set by tapping on the top portion of
   the desired slide, where the home symbol is.

Answer (score 0):

For Samsung, it is very simple, pinch your screen.

1. touch your screen using your two fingers (spread)
2. slide both fingers so that they will touch each other
3. You should see all the pages and you can do the rearranging

Enjoy!!!

Comment: The original posting is about a Nexus device running stock Android. Your solution is helpful for Samsung devices using TouchWiz, however.

Answer (score 0):

I use CLauncher almost specifically so I can set my Home screen.

It also themes up (default/popular) icons if you're in to that kind of thing.