# How to set default home screen on Android 4.4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, home-screen, aokp

I am using AOKP with Android 4.4.4. I figured out how to add additional home screens, but I can only add them to the right, and the default home screen (the one that I get taken to when I press the "home" button) is always the leftmost one.

In older versions I could add new home screens on both sides, so I could have the default home screen be in the middle for easy access. But I can't figure out how to set the default now. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I make my home screen the center instead of the left?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/61858/can-i-make-my-home-screen-the-center-instead-of-the-left)

Comment: Which launcher are you using in AOKP? Even if AOKP's default one, give us the name.

Comment: @Firelord Launcher3.